# One-to-one and one-to-many relationship in the same table is possible?

Tags: sql, postgresql, orm

I have Texts and Users tables. The user can be a corrector or writer. Each text has only one corrector and one writer. But each user can write many texts and a corrector can correct many texts. What is the correct way to model the relationship of these 2 tables?

Does the Text table need to have user_id and corrector_id fields? Or just make a many-to-many relationship?

If you need to have user_id and corrector_id fields, how would these 2 fields relate to the user table?
And if it is correct to use many-to-many what would be the correct way to get the data of the writer and the corrector of a text?

Thank you!

Comment: table : tblTexts TextID, CorrectorUserID, WriterUserID.   Each User ID would join to the users table  so `select * from tblTexts as t left join users as u1 on t.CorrectorUserID=u.UserID left join users as u2 on t.WriterUserID=u2.userid`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav but then the text table won't have a many-to-many relationship? Is it better for me to have the 2 fields writerId and correctorId?

Answer (score 0):

you can build a bridge table with a field that descrite the type of relationship(author corrector) as you have her a n:m relatiopnship between text and users

you need also zto make the columns of the user_text table unique so that you conditon that only 1 corrector and 1 writer is complied

```
users        user_text         text
user_id      user_id           text_id
             text_id
             type
```